# Custom search box does not filter top most ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, search-box

I am trying to create a custom search box that would filter ListBoxItems based on what is typed in the search box. Currently, it will filter based on the starting letter of the items name, so it grabs all the items that start with that letter. Ideally if the user types the full item name it should only display that item. My issue is that it will only filter the lower most item in the listbox when its full name is typed. For example, I have 1 item called **Deer**  and another called **Dog**, Deer is above Dog in the listbox if I type Deer it still displays Dog, but If I type Dog it only shows dog.

Below is an example of the problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iotEeyvyaiY

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<Rectangle> items = new List<Rectangle>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void HideAllNonMatch(ListBoxItem targetItem)
        {
            foreach (var tItem in listBox.Items)
            {
                var listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)tItem;

                // If the item does not match the target item, hide it.
                if (listBoxItem.Name != targetItem.Name)
                {
                    listBoxItem.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }
        private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            // Iterate through listbox Items.
            foreach (object? item in listBox.Items)
            {
                ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)item;

                // Check if searchbox first letter matches item first letter.
                if (searchBox.Text.StartsWith(listBoxItem.Name[0]))
                {
                    // Display the item if it begins with the matching letter.
                    listBoxItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    // If the searchBox text matches the items full name, hide all items that dont match.
                    if (searchBox.Text == listBoxItem.Name)
                    {
                        HideAllNonMatch(listBoxItem);
                    }
                }

                // If letter doesnt match, just hide the item.
                else
                {
                    listBoxItem.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                // If searchbox is blank show all items.
                if (searchBox.Text == "")
                {
                    listBoxItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Height="50" FontSize="15" Name="searchBox" TextChanged="searchBox_TextChanged"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Name="listBox" >
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="frog">
                <TextBlock Text="frog"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="fish">
                <TextBlock Text="fish"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="bear">
                <TextBlock Text="bear"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="bat">
                <TextBlock Text="bat"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="tiger">
                <TextBlock Text="tiger"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="lizard">
                <TextBlock Text="lizard"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="deer">
                <TextBlock Text="deer"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="dog">
                <TextBlock Text="dog"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Do you *have to* solve this in this horrible way (is this a homework)? Messing around with UIElements in code-behind is not the right way in WPF and also complicated. Are you familiar with [data binding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0), [CollectionViewSource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview?view=net-5.0), [ICollectionView.Filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.filter?view=net-5.0#System_ComponentModel_ICollectionView_Filter) & co?

Comment: @Steeeve It's not homework, But Im relatively new to C# and wpf. I was just watching a video of someone doing the something similar through code and I wanted to give it a try. But, thanks for the links Ill take a look at them.

Comment: Yeah, the youtube university... ;) It is probably much better to read the posted links (and even better some wpf books) and try to resolve it the 'right' way. Trying to fix the shown code would be wasted time, you won't ever need something like this ;)

Comment: Yeah I agree, it definitely is messy and its better to learn the correct way, also since you mentioned books a friend of mine is going to give me a book called wpf 4.5 unleashed, bit old but I heard its pretty good :D.